# Encountering Import Error DLL load failed constantly

Tags: python, compiler-errors, scikit-learn, pytorch

I have been trying to intall `scikit-learn` and `pytorch` using their respective commands given in the docs:

The commands for installing [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) are:

```
1) pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
2) pip3 install torchvision
```

The command for installing [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) is:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

***Some background:***

I am using Windows 8.1, Python 3.7.2. My `pip` is updated. I have also installed Anaconda for solving this using `conda`, but had zero luck!(Also, here I am running into 'conda' unrecognized error which is another story). Here are the paths my PATH variable holds.

```
PATH

C:\Users\satya\Anaconda3;
C:\Users\satya\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\Users\satya\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;
C:\Users\satya\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
C:\Users\satya\Anaconda3\Scripts; 
C:\Users\satya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;
C:\Users\satya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\; C:\Users\satya\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7
```

***The Actual Problem:***

The same commands for installation given above work perfectly fine on my other Windows 10, but, for my Windows 8.1 it gives this error which has become a real PITA

> Import Error: DLL load failed The specified module could not be found

When I `import sklearn` or `import torch` I get the exact same error. All the time.

***Back Story:***

I have searched almost all the related questions I could find on Stackoverflow and Github for 6+ hours to help me solve this problem. But, none of the answers have helped till now and some haven't had an "understandable" answer. Maybe, its just a small fix, but now, I am choosing to post a question on SO.

***My Question Again:***

Can someone please help out and try to explain what I am missing out here? I really want to fix this error for good(and want to be in a position to fix it if I encounter it again). An elaborate answer would really help understand easily.

Thank You!

Comment: Well, can you confirm that the dll it is located where it's supposed to be(the path should be somewhere in the stacktrace)?

Comment: Im sorry but I did not get you @meissner_

Comment: The Error tells you it didn't find some dll, did you have a look if it's in the place where your script is trying to import it from or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your python build number with the following command.

```
conda list python
```

Python 3.7.2 with build number h8c8aaf0_2 has [a solved issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10640).

If this is the case, an update will do.

```
conda update python
```

Comment: I had a different build number. But still, I tried it out the solution and now it works on Anaconda. If you could, can you please explain what the build number had to do with the problem? Also, could you suggest ways to solve the problem without anaconda?

Comment: The solution I used was from the github link you provided

Comment: It was explained in the link that "something got broken in the management of the DLL load path and hence the PyTorch DLL ... cannot be loaded".  Both the Anaconda team the the pytorch team were trying to solve this issue.  See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4518.  Update python to a higher build number meant an issue-free version.